# How to have module accessible globally with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, global-variables, global

In order not to import modules that I use a lot, in Javascript I have a global file with these modules that I import like this:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
global.useState = useState;
global.useEffect = useEffect;
global.useRef = useRef;
```

then I simply import them like this

```
import './util/react-globals';
```

I'd like to do the same thing with Typescript but I don't manage to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `export x from y` in TypeScript

globals.ts:

```
export { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//or even export * from "react";
export * from "mymodule";
```

and then in anotherfile.ts

```
import { x, y, z } from "./globals";
```

but there is no way you come around all the imports at the top

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then I lost the point of having a global file since I still need to import my modules

Comment: yeah, that's what I told you, there isn't really a way to "inject" your modules, at least not in plain JavaScript/TypeScript. One last tip: For own functions one can use namespaces or declare something globally, however I never did this with modules as it's not really recommended. Maybe take a look at this tho @Simon

Comment: Yes there is maybe a solution with this. I would be very surprised that something be impossible to do in Typescript but possible with Js